# want to develop iphone app alike Drinkspiration By absolut vodka

Tags: iphone, animation

anyone knows how "[Drinkspiration By Absolut](http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/drinkspiration-by-absolut/id320379903?mt=8)" developed. I want to do something similar to the card flipping effects. any hints on what should i learn and where do i start to do that? many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need custom graphics and the help of Core Animation. I suggest you buy a book on iPhone animation, as it will teach a lot more than the internet will.